# Blocking port 25 with iptables (outbound only)

Tags: iptables

I've recently started blocking port 25 on OpenVZ 7 nodes, using the following rule:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

This works fine, but it seems to block both inbound and outbound, but I only want outbound to be blocked. Is this possible?

If it means anything, I use the following commands to open port 25 again for a specific IP address:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Docker containers (or classic VMs in NAT mode) are not affected from INPUT- or OUTPUT-table. They are forwarded over your host - and that is the reason why only FORWARD-rules changes the behavior.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it was not helpful, as I read too fast and didn't notice we were dealing with containerization. Given the name of the interface in your container, you may have more luck with: `iptables -A FORWARD -o docker0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP`, where `docker0` if your interface name. As mentioned the traffic coming from the container goes through the FORWARD chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pleased to say that I've got this fully working, thanks to Kahn, here is the solution which should for others who are running OpenVZ 7:

Run the following:

`iptables -A FORWARD -o br0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP`

This will drop outbound port 25 on br0 (the interface that VMs inherit)

Then, if it needs opening for a specific IP address, run:

`iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I'm pleased it's working for you - would you be kind enough to accept my answer?

Answer (score 2):

**I've deleted my original answer because it was not helpful, as I read too fast and didn't notice we were dealing with containerization. The below comments can be ignored (unless you want to see how to log iptables activity).**

Given the name of the interface in your container, you may have more luck with:

`iptables -A FORWARD -o docker0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP`

Where `docker0` if your interface name. As mentioned the traffic coming from the container goes through the FORWARD chain (again - containerization), so the OUTPUT and INPUT chains are not valuable here.

Comment: I've just tried that rule (with no other iptables rules active), but both port 25 inbound and outbound were open.

Comment: Even still, what is the output of `iptables -L`?

Comment: `[root@fife ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp

Chain SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_IN (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain SOLUSVM_TRAFFIC_OUT (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root@fife ~]#`

Comment: Also, what means are you using to verify that port 25 is still pushing traffic out?

Comment: I tried sending an email out using cPanel Webmail (port 25) and it delivered fine. When I use the rule `iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP`, it does not deliver.

Comment: Got you. OK, let's try to capture what's happening here. Let's keep that OUTPUT block in there, and we'll toss in some logging: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-prefix "SMTP: "`. Attempt to mail a few times, and check `/var/log/messages`. Toss your output in your question (better formatting).

Comment: You'll want the logging line first, so `iptables -L` will look something like this: `Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp LOG level warning prefix SMTP: ' 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04 container (`FROM ubuntu:jammy`), I had to use the following

- Add `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` to the `docker run` command.
- `sudo iptables-legacy -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP`

without the `iptables-legacy`, I was getting a `unknown option "--dport"`
without `-A OUTPUT` it still allowed the outbound port